# Ignore NameError during iteration

Tags: python

I need to iterate over a list and do some operation (say for e.g `sum`). Whenever it gets a NameError, it should just skip that variable and return the remaining result set.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

try:
    z = sum([a, b, c, d])
except NameError as e:
    pass
else:
    print(z)
```

I haven't declared `d` here so when the exception is caught, it should just skip `d` and compute the remaining result. How to do this?

```
Expected result = 6
```

NOTE: I have named a, b, c, d explicitly for understanding but in real scenario, the list is populated differently.

Comment: Once `NameError` is raised, the `sum` is not calculated.

Comment: This is a really hard question to answer without knowing what you're really trying to do.  In this case, the `NameError` happens before the list gets constructed so you can't take the sum.  How do you end up with names that aren't defined?

Comment: I am trying to compute a excel formula like SUM(A1:A5), If A4 is not defined, I just need to skip that and compute others.

Comment: can you add the actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how you are ending up with undefined variables would help a lot but one way would be to parse the traceback to get the undefined variable name and give it a default value of 0:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    while True:
        try:
            z = sum([a, b, c, d])
            break
        except NameError as e:
            name = e.message.split()[1].strip("'")
            exec "{} = {}".format(name, 0)
    return z

print(f())
```

For python 3,  exec won't work so you would have to add the name to globals:

```
def f():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    while True:
        try:
            z = sum([a, b, c, d])
            break
        except NameError as e:
            name = str(e).split()[1].strip("'")
            globals()[name] = 0
    return z
```

Answer (score 4):

When `NameError` is raised, the `sum` function will not complete.
Here is one way to get around that. It is an odd approach but since you have a special situation, it could help.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

def checkExists(variable):
    return variable in locals() or variable in globals()

toCheck = []

# Check all the variables as strings to see if they exist
for var in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:
    # If they do, add them to the 'check' list
    if checkExists(var):
        toCheck.append(eval(var))

print(sum(toCheck))
```